# how to call Inner Class in C#

Tags: c#

i am trying to set inner class value from outer class using event handler

here the line for passing the value , PaymentMode is Event

```
public event PaymentModeEven PaymentMode;
PaymentMode(this,new PaymentModeEvenArgs() { paymentSuccess = true });
```

Inner Class

```
public class PaymentModeEvenArgs: EventArgs
{
    private bool PaymentSuccess;
    public bool paymentSuccess
    {
        get { return paymentSuccess; }
        set
        {
            paymentSuccess = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Program get stuck and stopped

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a stack overflow exception.  Consider your property:

```
public bool paymentSuccess
{
    get { return paymentSuccess; }
    set
    {
        paymentSuccess = value;
    }
}
```

When you get or set `paymentSuccess`, what does it do internally?  It gets or sets `paymentSuccess`.  Which, internally, gets or sets `paymentSuccess`.  Which, internally... You get the idea.

It looks like you meant to swap the casing between the field and the property:

```
private bool paymentSuccess;
public bool PaymentSuccess
{
    get { return paymentSuccess; }
    set
    {
        paymentSuccess = value;
    }
}
```

Or, even better, just use an auto-implemented property so you only have to make one named member:

```
public bool PaymentSuccess { get; set; }
```

Comment: Some advocate using an underscore prefix on private member variables, ie `_paymentSuccess`.  It makes errors like this one stand like a sore thumb.